# WPF update datagrid with datatable thread PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatable, datagrid

I have a object `StatusDb status` that fires a thread inside that keeps receiving a query data from a SQL Server.
I fill it using `SqlDataAdapter` `Fill(DataTable)` method.
When I set DataTable object to a member it calls `OnPropertyChanged` Like this:

```
private DataTable DT;
public DataTable dt
{
    get
    {
        return DT;
    }
    set
    {
        DT = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("dt");
    }
}
```

and in the XAML:

```
 <dg:DataGrid x:Name="dtStatus" Margin="10,32,10,10" Initialized="DataGrid_Initialized"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DefaultView}"
    DataContext="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=status.dt}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="True"></dg:DataGrid>
```

But the `DataGrid` is not having the columns and rows that it should.
I checked on debug mode that `DataTable` has values on it and it's not a SQL query problem.

Comment: ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DefaultView}" ??

Comment: Try filling a data table that is not `dt`, then assign that instance to `dt`. I mocked it up and it works for me.

Comment: ok done. not working. I think the issue maybe is in XAML. ItemsSource and DataContext.

Comment: Did the columns get generated correctly?  If your datagrid has no column (header) than your datacontext is wrong.  probably because status is not a public property.  If you have headers but no row, you need to post more codes.